# Restore files from before git pull

Tags: git, github, commit, pull, revert

I have a problem with a git repository. I will describe what I did.

- I have created a repository in side an existing folder with files using the command `git init`
- I added a remote with `git add origin git @ ...`
- Instead of commit I used the command `git pull origin master` what override my files, files with an empty repository

Is there any way to restore my files?

Comment: A `git pull` shouldn't mess with uncommitted local changes.  Are you sure they are gone?  When I try what you said you did, I get an "error: Untracked working tree file <foo> would be overwritten by merge"

Comment: Yes, they are gone... I dont know why... Here is my terminal history:git init
git st
git add -A
git remote add origin git@github.co...
git pull origin master

Comment: @Joe I can reproduce this, there's no warning when I'm doing a pull within a fresh repository without any commits (just files in the index).

Comment: @Stefan what version of git?  Because I got the results I posted after trying it, before commenting.  Hmm.

Comment: @Joe 1.8.3.1: `mkdir foo && cd foo && git init . && touch bar && git add bar && git remote add origin git://github.com/github/gollum.git && git pull origin master` doesn't show an error on my system and silently removes `bar` from the repo. I do see the error when there's at least one commit, but not for a repo without commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a git pull is a fetch and a merge so is reversable for security checkout a new branch:

```
git checkout -b restore
```

then go back with

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Comment: you're right, since you don't have commited. If your files were so important check http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Thanks! From a cat-file command was able to recover all the files.